# Where to buy a shas/talmud in one volume?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara

I have seen, once or twice, the entire talmud printed in one volume. The book was larger than your average book/gemara and there were 4 amudim printed on each page (with Rashi and Tosfos) according to the Vilna layout.

Is such a book available anywhere for sale?

Does anyone have a link to a picture of such a talmud or anyone talking about it or who published it?

Answer (score 5):

It is available at [www.aron-hasofrim.co.il](http://www.aron-hasfarim.co.il/product.asp?productid=129) for 525 Shekel. It is also available by [www.lehmanns.co.uk](http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/tlmvd-bbli-hwlm-bkrk-ahd-hvcat-aiil-w-s-bkrk-ahd.html) for 67.50 pounds,

Answer (score 2):

OZ V'hadar did a new printing of this:

https://ozvehadar.us/shas-talmud-bavli-in-one-volume/

Sample page :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a copy of it form Nehora.com for $54.00 using this link;
[https://www.amazon.com/Sefer-Imros-Tehoros-Yehudah-Hebrew/dp/B008JKYYOG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008JKYYOG)

Comment: I think that this isn't the right link (You liked to Amazon and not Nehora)

Comment: I have the Talmud Bavli you are talking about (it was from Nehora and was $54.00) and I must say it does not have the classic Vilna Shas layout, nor the Rashi and Tosfos or any of the other marginal notes in normal Gemaros. It just has the text of the Gemara, unvowelized, with section headers telling you the corresponding daf section in a normal Gemara. Useful tool still, just not exactly the thing the OP was asking for.