# Quadrant based layout for the Yerushalmi

Tags: writing-printing, talmud-yerushalmi

If one goes through the citations in the Milon Even Shoshan, one might see references to words from the Yerushalmi with attribution like this:

[image: image of relevant text from the dictionary]

Please zoom in and look at the entry for pileish, on the last line of the right column of page 1298. The reference is to ירושלמי סוכה נג ד

The amud is "dalet". I had it explained to me that an early printing of the [Yerushalmi](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45298&st=&pgnum=3) was in 4 columns so the citation for amud is to the particular column.

However, I vaguely recall a Yerushalmi in which there were quadrants on the page. I don't know if I am remembering some version of the text described in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55163/where-to-buy-a-shas-talmud-in-one-volume) question, or it there is another layout of the Yerushalmi using quadrants which specifically explains the aleph-dalet amud references. Does anyone know of a quadrant based layout specifically for the Yerushalmi?

Comment: The reference to ammud gimmel usually refers to pages with more than one column per page.

Answer (score 7):

The reference is to the pages of the [Venice printing of the Talmud Yerushalmi](http://hebrewbooks.org/45298) (5283/1523). Each folio is divided into four columns, two on each side of the page, and these are the numbers of the amud (1 and 2 on the front, 3 and 4 on the back).

The sentence quoted from page 53d (Sukka, chapter 3, law 6) appears in the middle of the left column of [this page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45298&st=&pgnum=235).

Below is a picture of a newer, clearer typeset maintaining the original Venice pagination.

[image]

Comment: @Oliver Interestingly the division into columns is off by a few words

Comment: Part of the reason I only wrote “pagination” ;) (hope still useful)