# Talmud Yerushalmi: comparing paginations

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-yerushalmi

As far as I'm aware, there are three different popular paginations of the Talmud Yerushalmi: the [Venice edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/45298) (four volumes, [two columns](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55268/15256) per *amud*), the Vilna edition (one column per *amud*), and the more recent Oz VeHadar edition (used in Artscroll's edition). Additionally, sections of the Yerushalmi are often cited by chapter and *halacha*.

Luckily, the Oz VeHadar (and hence Artscroll) edition lists the corresponding page in the Vilna edition, making the transition between the two relatively painless. I haven't found anything similar for the other schemes.

Are there conversion charts between references to the Venice edition and those to the Vilna edition? Are there charts that list which pages in the Venice/Vilna edition contain which *halachot*?

Comment: Where does this come up for you?

Comment: BTW, which page scheme is used by Jastrow? It's not Vilna.