# Jerusalem Talmud: pagination on Sefaria

Tags: internet, talmud-yerushalmi

Sefaria paginates the Jerusalem Talmud thus: 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b etc. This isn't the standard system for paginating Yerushalmi that I'm familiar with, which which is by tur rather than by amud. Can anyone help me with where Sefaria is getting their system from?

If it helps, it seems to be the same system that the Responsa Project has for various Yerushalmi commentaries (P'nei Moshe, Korban haEidah etc) so it must be from some standard edition but I don't know which one...

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109211/759

Comment: Have you considered asking Sefaria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sefaria seems to be using the Vilna pagination system.

I confirmed this to be the case for Berachot by comparing Sefaria's pagination with the [Vilna edition Yerushalmi](http://hebrewbooks.org/40733) available at HebrewBooks.org.

I would imagine that the same holds true for the other *masechtot* as well.

Comment: Given that the Daf Yomi Yerushalmi uses that edition, it's the likely choice.

By the way, there is more than one Vilna edition; you mean the Radba"z's; the one with his peirush on the inside of the page.